# Why OpenGL ES texture lookup changes so much with different coordinates (BOTH from vertex shader)?

Tags: performance, opengl-es, coordinates, textures, lookup

I'm developing a game for Android with OpenGL ES 2.0.
I have to access 4 different texture maps in the fragment shader to apply a multitexture to a terrain (texture splatting).
The problem I'm facing is that accessing the same texture maps with different coordinates gives as output a difference of almost 10 fps.
Both the coordinates are calculated in the vertex shader, in the fragment shader there are only the texture lookups.
I cannot explain such a huge difference in performance.

**Vertex shader**

```
...
varying vec2 vTextureCoordinates; 
varying vec2 vTextureCoordinates2;

void main() {
...
vTextureCoordinates = textureCoordinates;
vTextureCoordinates2 = textureCoordinates * 16.0;
...

gl_Position = MVPMatrix * position;
}
```

**Fragment shader**

```
...
uniform sampler2D textureBlack;
uniform sampler2D textureRed;
uniform sampler2D textureGreen;
uniform sampler2D textureBlue;
uniform sampler2D blendMap;

varying vec2 vTextureCoordinates;
varying vec2 vTextureCoordinates2;

void main() {
...

vec4 blendColor = texture2D(blendMap, vTextureCoordinates);

float black = 1.0 - (blendColor.r + blendColor.g + blendColor.b);

// 28 FPS -> OK 
//  vec4 blackColor = texture2D(textureBlack, vTextureCoordinates) * black;
//  vec4 redColor = texture2D(textureRed, vTextureCoordinates) * blendColor.r;
//  vec4 greenColor = texture2D(textureGreen, vTextureCoordinates) * blendColor.g;
//  vec4 blueColor = texture2D(textureBlue, vTextureCoordinates) * blendColor.b;

// 20 FPS!!!
vec4 blackColor = texture2D(textureBlack, vTextureCoordinates2) * black;
vec4 redColor = texture2D(textureRed, vTextureCoordinates2) * blendColor.r;
vec4 greenColor = texture2D(textureGreen, vTextureCoordinates2) * blendColor.g;
vec4 blueColor = texture2D(textureBlue, vTextureCoordinates2) * blendColor.b;

vec3 fragColor = vec3(blackColor + redColor + greenColor + blueColor);
```

Comment: I guess vTextureCoordinates2 are out of range [0..1,0..1], that's why texture2D performs additional extrapolation/interpolation algorithm. It can be better way to modify textures, then to manipulate with coordinates.

Comment: Also you can recalc texture coordinates to range [0..1,0..1] in vertex shader. You will gain in performance because fragment shader executes more often.

Comment: While the `28 FPS` section is commented out, `vTextureCoordinates` is still being used for the `blendColor` texture lookup. But if you use `vTextureCoordinates` for both lookups, the shader compiler will be able to optimize `vTextureCoordinates2` away entirely, resulting in less data being sent between the vertex and fragment shader. To check if this is the case, try and see what happens if you use `vTextureCoordinates2` for the `blendColor` as well.

Comment: Hi Hihikomori, yes, what you said was also my thought. Nonetheless, again it seems an absurd increase of fps only due to this reason; i.e., adding the normal mapping calculations to the fragment shader did not give such an increase. The coordinates have been multiplied by 16 because I use the corresponding textures as tiling for the terrain.